# Telerik Radgrid: accidentally populating grid with all query fields

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using the telerik rad grid.  I successfully import the data & the 6 fields I choose to use, however after these 6 fields, my radgrid is reimporting ALL fields from my database query, using their field names as the column headers.  So in total, my query calls 9 fields, so I have a total of 15 columns.  My 6 that I want to have (plus 2 add'l columns for "Edit" & "Delete"), plus the 9 from my query.
The headers I want are as follows:
**Name | Description | Image | Start Date | End Date | Active**

Instead, I get this:
**Name | Description | Image | Start Date | End Date | Active | Email Promotion Id | Promotion Title | Promotion Description | Image Name | Start Date | End Date | Deep Link Id | Active | Update Username**

Here's my radgrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid 
      ID="rgPromotions"
      runat="server" 
      AllowPaging="true" 
      AllowSorting="true" 
      autopostback="false" 
      OnItemDataBound="rgPromotions_ItemDataBound"
      OnNeedDataSource="rgPromotions_NeedDataSource"
      Skin="Office2007">
      <MasterTableView  DataKeyNames="EmailPromotionId" Width="100%" TableLayout="Fixed"  AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" >
         <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
        <HeaderStyle Width="20px" ></HeaderStyle>
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
         <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>           

       <Columns>
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PromotionTitle" HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="PromotionTitle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="true" />
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PromotionDescription" HeaderText="Description"  SortExpression="PromotionDescription" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="true" />
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="Image"  SortExpression="ImageName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="true" />
          <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="StartDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter Start Date column" HeaderText="Start Date" PickerType="DatePicker" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ReadOnly="true"/>
          <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="EndDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter End Date column" HeaderText="End Date" PickerType="DatePicker" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ReadOnly="true"/>
          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="true"/>             
          <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EmailPromotionId" HeaderText="" ColumnGroupName="Edit" AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="EmailPromotionIdEdit"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEmailPromotionEdit_Click" CommandName="EmailPromotionId" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmailPromotionId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="EmailPromotionId" HeaderText="" ColumnGroupName="Edit" AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="EmailPromotionIdEdit"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnEmailPromotionDelete_Click" CommandName="EmailPromotionId" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmailPromotionId") %>'></asp:LinkButton> 
           </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
       </Columns>
      </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Any idea how I'm accidentally importing these additional fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` in your grid's main definition:

```
<telerik:RadGrid 
    ID="rgPromotions"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    ...
```